# Adding gravity effect to UI elements in OS X app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift

**EDIT**: To make the question clearer, I'll quote what Chris said in the comment, the question is "How can I do on OS X what UIKit Dynamics does on iOS?"

I want to add gravity effect to my UI elements in my OS X app, and I wonder if there are some best practices?

If I were developing an iOS app, I would turn to dynamic features introduced to `UIKit` in iOS7, but I couldn't find anything like that in `AppKit`. I've even tried to use `Sprite Kit` in a AppKit based app for its [physics simulation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html), but I couldn't find a way to remove the annoying grey background in `SKView` even when I've set `background` to `SKColor.clearColor()`.

So, I wonder if adding gravity is really that hard? Is there any best practices? I've found some apps, like `Pixelmator`, integrated some cool gravity features, so I guess that's possible? Can anyone help me out of here? Big thanks!

A small discussion: with the release of OS X 10.10, Apple is abandoning skeuomorphism, so is it still a good idea in design to add physics simulation in your app? Like the rope effect in Pixelmator app?

Comment: This is a pretty confusing question. What exactly do you mean by "simulating gravity"? Purely physics simulation in the software or something to do with device sensors? Why would it not be "the right thing" and what does OS X 10.10 have to do with it?

Comment: @Juhana, sorry for my poor expression. I've mentioned dynamics in UIKit and Sprite Kit, so I thought it would be clear enough that I mean adding physics simulation (say gravity) to my UI elements. And I've updated for it. As of the 10.10 discussion, since apple is abandoning skeuomorphism in 10.10, I wonder if simulating a rope as in Pixelmator app is a bad idea in design?

Comment: Seems a pretty clear question to me: How can I do on OS X  what UIKit Dynamics does on iOS?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDevereux for your advice, I'll add that to my question!